# Dynamically create arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to import a CSV file using PHPEXCEL. I got all the data from the file in an array. The problem is that it isn't a standard format and there are many header rows, followed by data until the next header row. I wish to save the data for each column between two header rows in a separate arrays but I want to create the variables dynamically since the location and the name of the header column could change.

So far, I've tried creating them with:

```
${$myData[headerRow][headerColumn]} = array();
```

In a for, to create a different array for each headerColumn from each headerRow, but it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use a multi-dimensional array instead, for example `$results['data'][$headerRowName][$headerColumnName] = [];`

Answer (score 0):

Initialise an array

```
$array = array();
```

Add to an array:

```
$array[] = "item";
$array[$key] = "item";
array_push($array, "item", "another item");
```

Remove from an array:

```
$item = array_pop($array);
$item = array_shift($array);
unset($array[$key]);
```